# How do I play loaded sound in chunks?

Tags: javascript, audio

Is it possible to load a compressed mp3 file, take small chunk, decode it to PCM and play, one by one? By far what I saw is an ability to decode the *entire* mp3 file to PCM, but it eats too much memory. What if I have 20 mp3 files that I need to play simultaneously? It will just crash when I try to decompress them all.

I need this for my online DAW station that I build.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great solution to this, someone already took care of the same problem I have:

https://github.com/audiocogs/aurora.js/

These guys wrote a special framework for implementing any sound decoder and revealed some examples, including mp3. They have AAC too, which is much better for my needs! Thank you guys, especially a guy, who gave me -1 for some mysterious reason.